# Log4j to print nested exceptions in one line

Tags: java, kotlin, log4j, log4j2

I would like log4j in my kotlin project to log multiple nested exceptions to one line.

For example, from:

```
try {
    throw IllegalArgumentException("a")
}
catch(e1: Exception) {
    try {
        throw IllegalStateException("a", e1)
    }
    catch(e2: Exception) {
        log.error("Nested", e2);
    }
}
```

I would like log.error to print: "Nested - a - b".

Comment: Why not log `e1.getMessage() + " - " + e2.getMessage()`, or whatever the kotlin equivalent would be? (Note: you don't need to catch and throw an exception: you can just create it like any other object, and use it without throwing it)

Comment: because this is just an example, in the real case the exceptions are caught and nested at different levels along the call stack and when you catch the exception at the top level you don't know how many nested exceptions you are dealing with.

Comment: there is no default for it - you will have to writer a loop to iterate while getCause is not null ... and concatenate

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PatternLayout to format your output there is currently no way to format it like that without some customization. Looking at ThrowablePatternConverter it looks like it could use an enhancement to support different formatting options as Plugins. If you would care to create a Jira issue for that I would consider implementing support for that. As it stands, you would have to create your own customized version of ThrowablePatternConverter.